# Repetir um numero de vezes em um intervalo de dias

Tags: php, data

Tenho esse código que repete um número de vezes o dia de cada semana.

```
$hoje = new DateTime();
$semana = new DateInterval('P7D');
$repeticoes = 3;

// Printa primeira data antes de somar os dias
echo  $hoje->format('Y-m-d '.$_POST['hora_inicio'].":00".'') . "\n<br>";
echo  $hoje->format('Y-m-d '.$_POST['hora_final'].":00".'') . "\n<br><br>";



// Como já foi printada a primeira data, repete N-1 vezes
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $repeticoes - 1 ; $i++) {
    // Adiciona uma semana
    $hoje = $hoje->add($semana);
    // Printa data adicionada
echo $hoje->format('Y-m-d '.$_POST['hora_inicio'].":00".'') . "\n<br>";
echo  $hoje->format('Y-m-d '.$_POST['hora_final'].":00".'') . "\n<br><br>";          
 }
```

**Saída do código acima**

```
2018-11-09

2018-11-16

2018-11-23
```

Minha dívida seria a seguinte:

Como eu posso fazer para repetir o intervalo entre os dias estipulando uma data limite?

**Exemplo:**

Data de hoje: **09/11/2018**

Numero de vezes para repetir entre os dias: **3**

Data de término: **16/11/2018**

Preciso que imprima:

**09/11/2018**

**12/11/2018**

**15/11/2018**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesses casos o ideal é fazer com `while`, não que não seja possível fazer com `for`, mas o `for` geralmente é utilizado com números inteiros.

```
<?php
    $data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '09/11/2018'); // Define a data inicial
    $fim = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '16/11/2018'); // Define a data final
    $intervaloDias = 3; // Define o intervalo de dias

    while ($data->format('Y-m-d') <= $fim->format('Y-m-d')) { // Verifica se a data é menor que a data final

        echo $data->format('Y-m-d ') . "\n"; // Escreve a data na tela

        $data = $data->add(new DateInterval('P'.$intervaloDias.'D')); // Incrementa a data
    }
?>
```

**Resultado**

> 2018-11-09
>   2018-11-12
>   2018-11-15

Montei o código de forma que qualquer pessoa consiga testa-lo e vê-lo funcionando, então, será necessário você fazer algumas alterações para atender o contexto do seu código, são alterações básicas para atribuir as datas nas variáveis.

Veja funcionando no [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/7UNI1x).